# Handling an exception thrown by a Spring Data repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot app I have the following service method

```
@Override
public SourcingOrganisation createOrganisation(
        SourcingOrganisation sourcingOrganisation) {

    try {
        return sourcingOrganisationRepository.save(sourcingOrganisation);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        throw new DomainObjectAlreadyExistsException(ex);
    }
}
```

where `sourcingOrganisationRepository` is an instance of `CrudRepository`.

If I try to call `sourcingOrganisationRepository.save` with data that violates a unique index, a `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception is thrown which contains a nested `ConstraintViolationException`

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [u_ci_sourcing_organisations_name]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
```

I try to rethrow this is a `DomainObjectAlreadyExistsException` (because I have a global exception handler that will cause this to return a 409 HTTP status), but for some reason my `catch` block is never executed. I verified this by setting a breakpoint in the catch block, and also by checking the call stack of the thrown exception for references to my service class (there are none).

I tried changing my catch block to catch all exceptions, but it still wasn't executed. Why isn't this catch block being executed, and is there there some other way to translate the exception thrown by this repository method?

Comment: What do you mean ***is never invoked*** ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I mean it's never executed

Comment: How do you know it is never executed?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I've explained this in the 2nd last paragraph

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace, it looks like the exception doesnt occur during your invocation of `save`. My guess is that the exception occurs after all of your code finishes, when spring tries to commit the transaction. Do you have an @Transactional annotation somewhere?

Comment: @codeflush.dev yes, the controller class is annotated with `@Transactional`

Comment: The Exception is only catchable when invoking the method of your controller (or further in the stack). You wont be able to catch it inside your controller or deeper.

Comment: have you tried to not throwing the actual exception? For example. throw new DomainObjectAlreadyExistsException("My exception message"). And also what is a parent class of DomainObjectAlreadyExistsException?